# How can I read a YAML file with PHP?

Tags: php, html, yaml

How can I read a YAML file with PHP? What I want is something like a reader.

Me and my friends are creating a Minecraft server and we want connect the server to site. For that we need a reader to read the YAML file that is in our server files. This file is called users.yml and inside it is the next code:

```yaml
users:
  80679a11-1d47-3a0e-8346-4790ee4304fc:     <<<< Player Code.
    group:
    - Admin                                 <<<< Player Group.
    options:
      name: JamesMarch                      <<<< Player Nick Name.
  56874a35-8f52-5f2c-7843-7788je9670tb:     <<<< Player Code.
    group:
    - Admin                                 <<<< Player Group.
    options:
      name: Angelow98                       <<<< Player Nick Name.
  55026444-cb34-3a27-a270-d7d07fccca0a:     <<<< Player Code.
    group:
    - Helper                                <<<< Player Group.
    options:
      name: iDatSnoow_                      <<<< Player Nick Name.
```

When a new player connects to the server to play, this file automatically creates a new paragraph like this (This is a new player):

```yaml
  84569a84-5d77-3a5e-8547-4720ee4304fc:   <<<< Player Code.
    group:
    - NewPlayer                           <<<< Player Group (NewPlayer is the default group)
    options:
      name: mumiant_                      <<<< Player Nick Name.
```

To make the player an administrator, for example, one of the administrators, has to enter this command: `/manuadd (player name) Admin`, and it will automatically edit in `users.yml`.

In our website, on the home page, we would like to show, in a box, the most important groups (helpers and administrators) like this simple HTML code:

```html
<h1>Staff</h1>
    <h2>Administrators</h2>
        <p>Angelow98</p>
        <p>JamesMarch</p>
    <h2>Helper</h2>
        <p>iDatSnoow_</p>
```

In conclusion, what we want is that it work automatically. This is, when someone becomes an administrator, the PHP reader will read the YAML code and it will print on website, like the HTML code above.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can parse YAML and dump an array to YAML using [symfony/yaml](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/introduction.html):

```
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;
$yaml = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents('/path/to/file.yml'));
$yamlString = Yaml::dump($yaml);
```

Now to parse your example, I replaced the `<<<<` with valid YAML comments:

```
$data = \Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml::parse('users:
  80679a11-1d47-3a0e-8346-4790ee4304fc:     # Player Code.
    group:
    - Admin                                 # Player Group.
    options:
      name: JamesMarch                      # Player Nick Name.
  56874a35-8f52-5f2c-7843-7788je9670tb:     # Player Code.
    group:
    - Admin                                 # Player Group.
    options:
      name: Angelow98                       # Player Nick Name.
  55026444-cb34-3a27-a270-d7d07fccca0a:     # Player Code.
    group:
    - Helper                                # Player Group.
    options:
      name: iDatSnoow_                      # Player Nick Name.');
```

Now let's group all players by their first assigned group:

```
$groups = array();
foreach ($data['users'] as $playerCode => $player) {
    $firstGroupName = $player['group'][0];
    $groups[$firstGroupName][$playerCode] = $player;
}
```

`$groups` now looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [Admin] => Array
        (
            [80679a11-1d47-3a0e-8346-4790ee4304fc] => Array
                (
                    [group] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Admin
                        )
                    [options] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => JamesMarch
                        )
                )
            [56874a35-8f52-5f2c-7843-7788je9670tb] => Array
                (
                    [group] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Admin
                        )
                    [options] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Angelow98
                        )
                )
        )

    [Helper] => Array
        (
            [55026444-cb34-3a27-a270-d7d07fccca0a] => Array
                (
                    [group] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Helper
                        )

                    [options] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => iDatSnoow_
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

If you pass that array to a PHP template, you could achieve your output like this:

```
<?php foreach($groups as $group => $players): ?>
<h1><?= $group ?></h1>
<?php foreach ($players as $playerCode => $player): ?>
<p><?= $player['options']['name'] ?> </p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I don´t know how to install Symfony in my website... How I install?

Comment: You don't need all of Symfony, only the Yaml library. Nowadays it's best practice to install PHP libraries via Composer: https://getcomposer.org/
Once set up, a simple `composer require symfony/yaml` would download it and make it available via Composer's autoloader.
Anyway, this is out of scope for this question, so if you can't get it working, create a new question on SO.

Comment: it gave me this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'a11' (T_STRING), expecting ']' in /home/u471174751/public_html/staff.php on line 38

line 38 is this:  [80679a11-1d47-3a0e-8346-4790ee4304fc] => Array